# Constructor call of function local static object skipped

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I have written the following function:

```
inline void putc(int c)
{
  static Cons_serial serial;

  if (serial.enabled())
    serial.putc(c);
}
```

Where `Cons_serial` is a class with a non-trivial default constructor. I believe the exact class definition is not important here but you can correct me on that. I'm compiling for x86 32 bit with `g++` using the following flags: `-m32 -fno-PIC -ffreestanding -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-threadsafe-statics -O0`, the generated assembly code for `putc` looks like this:

```
00100221 <_Z4putci>:
  100221:       55                      push   %ebp
  100222:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
  100224:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  100227:       b8 f8 02 10 00          mov    $0x1002f8,%eax
  10022c:       0f b6 00                movzbl (%eax),%eax
  10022f:       84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  100231:       75 18                   jne    10024b <_Z4putci+0x2a>
  100233:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  100236:       68 f0 02 10 00          push   $0x1002f0
  10023b:       e8 36 fe ff ff          call   100076 <_ZN11Cons_serialC1Ev>
  100240:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
  100243:       b8 f8 02 10 00          mov    $0x1002f8,%eax
  100248:       c6 00 01                movb   $0x1,(%eax)
  10024b:       83 ec 0c                sub    $0xc,%esp
  10024e:       68 f0 02 10 00          push   $0x1002f0
  100253:       e8 4c fe ff ff          call   1000a4 <_ZNK11Cons_serial7enabledEv>
  100258:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
  10025b:       84 c0                   test   %al,%al
  10025d:       74 13                   je     100272 <_Z4putci+0x51>
  10025f:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
  100262:       ff 75 08                pushl  0x8(%ebp)
  100265:       68 f0 02 10 00          push   $0x1002f0
  10026a:       e8 41 fe ff ff          call   1000b0 <_ZN11Cons_serial4putcEi>
  10026f:       83 c4 10                add    $0x10,%esp
  100272:       90                      nop
  100273:       c9                      leave  
  100274:       c3                      ret
```

During execution, the jump at `100231` is taken the first time the function runs, thus `Cons_serial` is never called. Why knowledge of x86 assembly is questionable, what do the instructions leading up to that one actually do? I assume the code is meant to skip the constructor call on subsequent function calls. But then why is it skipped the first time the function runs as well?

EDIT: This code is part of a kernel I'm writing and I suspect the root cause might be an issue with my kernel's .bss section, here is the linker script I use:

```
OUTPUT_FORMAT("elf32-i386")

ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
  . = 0x100000;
  .text : AT(0x100000) {
    *(.text)
  }

  .data : SUBALIGN(2) {
    *(.data);
    *(.rodata*);
  }

  .bss : SUBALIGN(4) {
    __bss_start = .;
    *(.COMMON);
    *(.bss*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    __bss_end = .;
  }

  /DISCARD/ : {
    *(.eh_frame)
    *(.comment)
  }
}
```

And here's the code I use to zero the .bss section:

```
extern uint32_t __bss_start;
extern uint32_t __bss_end;

void zero_bss()
{
  for (uint32_t bss_addr = __bss_start; bss_addr < __bss_end; ++bss_addr)
    *reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(bss_addr) = 0x00;
}
```

But when `zero_bss` runs, `__bss_start` is `0x27` and `__bss_end` is `0x101` which is not at all what I'd except (the BSS should encompass address `0x1002f8` after all).

Comment: Why do you think it is skipped the first time the function runs?

Comment: @DanielLangr: If I set a breakpoint inside the constructor it is never hit. And when I single step through the first execution of `putc` the jump that skips the constructor is taken.

Comment: That's quite weird. There is clearly a flag at `0x1002f8` address that is set once the constructor is called. But we likely cannot tell more until we see the complete minimal reproducible example. Plus the build setup (which GCC, Windows?, Linux?) Could you possibly do this in the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/)?

Comment: @DanielLangr: Yes, it is weird, I will try to make this reproducible somehow but it's very difficult since this snippet is part of a kernel I'm writing that's running inside qemu so I suppose it could be some problem with my build chain or bootloader.

Comment: There also might be some problem with a debugger. Have you tried to detect the constructor call some other way? Such as with some log messages?

Comment: @DanielLangr: The constructor sets up serial console IO and if it is not called, subsequent print requests don't work. So that's how I know it definitely never runs.

Comment: Have you considered that `0x1002f8` already has non-zero value in it ? That could happen if `.bss` section (or whatever it's called on x86) is not cleaned.

Comment: @user3124812: That's a really good hint. I know I have to do this manually but maybe my bootloader does not do this properly. I will investigate that, thanks.

Comment: @user3124812: That's almost certainly the root cause, I have added some info to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not an expert in Linker Scripts. At these rare moments when I need to do them, I just look into resulting 'LINK.MAP' file and edit script until get expected result :( . As side note, I'd do `*reinterpret_cast<uint32_t *>(bss_addr) = 0x00; bss_addr+= sizeof(uint32_t);` Linker script ensures word alignment.

Answer (score 3):

I've solved it now, the hint from @user3124812 was what got me there, thanks again.
My `zero_bss` code was faulty, I needed to take the *addresses* of the `__bss*` markers from the linker script, i.e.:

```
extern uint8_t __bss_start;
extern uint8_t __bss_end;

void zero_bss()
{
  uint8_t *bss_start = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&__bss_start);
  uint8_t *bss_end = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t *>(&__bss_end);

  for (uint8_t *bss_addr = bss_start; bss_addr < bss_end; ++bss_addr)
    *bss_addr = 0x00;
}
```

Now everything works.

Comment: If you declare `extern char __bss_start[0];` you can just use the symbol; that's the closest analogy to an asm label name.  And being zero-width (sizeof(__bss_start) == 0), it won't even overlap with another C object, and the compiler should hopefully warn you if you try to deref it because any access would be outside the array bounds.  (Although it will still have the same address as the first var in the BSS).

Comment: BTW, you probably want to call `memset` for this.  Your kernel should already have a decently optimized memset function, perhaps just using `rep stosb` in inline asm, so do that to let it run faster than a byte loop.  (With `-fbuiltin-memset`, GCC may turn this loop into a memset call itself)